# Form 8843 - Statement for Exempt Individuals - Do I need to complete a closer connection form?

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, f1-student-visa

I am a Canadian citizen that has studied and worked in the US over the past 5 years. I am unsure how to complete Part III Questions 11 and 12 on the Form 8843.

I was on an F1 from Aug 2010 - May 2014, a TN Visa from October 2014 to November 2015, lived in Canada from November 2015 - July 2017 and am now on an F1 visa (started in July 2017).

Question 11: Do I indicate TN for 2015? **TN is not a listed visa option.**

Question 12: Have I been present as a student for any part of more than 5 calendar years? **Does this only date back to 2011?** **Do I include my years in US on a TN visa in this year count?**

Comment: Is there a reason you want to be a nonresident alien instead of a resident alien?

Answer (score 0):

You have already been an "exempt individual" for some part of at least 5 previous calendar years -- you would have been an "exempt individual" as a student during your time on F1 status in 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, and 2014 (unless you were an "exempt individual" in earlier years and met this 5 year limit even earlier).

Therefore, you are not an "exempt individual" as a student during your time on F1 status in 2017 (and cannot file Form 8843), unless you can claim "closer connection to a foreign country".

If you are filing Form 8843 because you claim to be an "exempt individual" during your time on F1 in 2017 due to a "closer connection to a foreign country", you would check Yes for question 12, and attach evidence of your closer connection to a foreign country. TN does not have to be listed in question 11.